# How to compile C program

Tags: c

I am learning C and I have a simple hello world program that I am trying to run on Windows 10. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I have installed GCC compiler and I tried the following in order to run it in the command prompt:

```
gcc hello.c
a
```

I also tried:

```
gcc hello.c
./a.exe
```

and:

```
gcc hello.c
./a
```

and:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
./hello
```

The program does not run displaying hello, world and it gives the following error:

```
bash: a.exe: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I run the program after the compilation?

[image: console output]

Comment: Can you give us the error? In the question said "it gives the following error" but you then forgot to add it

Comment: Did you open a command prompt? Post a screenshot just before execution (after "gcc hello.c", before "a.exe").

Comment: I used a command prompt, yes I updated the answer with the screenshot and error

Comment: You could have edited the image a little bit. Only 5% of the image contains useful information.

Comment: Have you tried any method to see if there is a file there?

Comment: After running `gcc`, what new files are there in the folder? There should be an `.exe` file, even if it's not named `a.exe`

Comment: (Also - and this is slightly off-topic - if you're under Windows, why not use an IDE like Visual Studio Community Edition? It's free, and a much better development experience than command line and notepad)

Comment: don't put a dot at the end of a file name like `2./a.exe`. [That may get you into trouble](https://superuser.com/q/1193102/241386#comment1733631_1193102)

Comment: Instead of trying to run all variants of the possible outputs, why not do a `ls` and see what the output file name is?  Also, you can use the `-o file` option in gcc and control the output file name.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your compilation succeeded successfully.

See if there is an `a.out` or `a.exe` file present, as you didn't indicate a non-default executable name.

Note that running `a` alone typically won't do anything, because it is highly unlikely that your executable is on the bash `PATH`.  This means you need to run `./a.out` or `./a` (depending on base operating system).

Answer (score 0):

Binary executables under windows typically must have `.exe` extension to be recognized as such.

I am not sure if gcc under windows adds the right extension automaticaly when outputting executables.

I would try:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
./hello.exe
```

Comment: yes, gcc does add .exe extension